# I get authenticated in some Django pages and in some not

Tags: django, authentication

**I'd like to know why is happening this.**

- I open my Django project (at 127.0.0.1:8000) and it appears my index
  page as I've set it in URLs and views.
- At the top I have a piece of code that if I'm authenticated it
  appears some text, and if not, another one.
- It appears when I open the index page that I'm not authenticated, but
  when I click a link in my menu to other page in my project, it
  appears that I'm actually authenticated.

  *I'm looking in the web for possible explanations but can't find out an answer to why I'm authenticated or logged in in a page and then in another not.*

How could this be possible, and how could I manage it?

Comment: It would help if you could show an example view to a page that shows you're not authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for @login_required decorator over your view functions. The documentation is at:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to answer your question without seeing your code, but it sounds like you are not passing the request context to your index view. Make sure you are using the [`render` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) in your views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
   return render(request, 'index.html')
```